# Unity webapps icons names

Tags: unity, icons, webapps

So, as you know Unity has those unity webapps which is basically a service that allow certain websites to integrate with the Unity desktop.

Youtube integrates with the sound menu, reddit with the messaging menu, etc ...

When you install a certain webapp it creates an app for itself in the Unity dash and needless to say this app has an icon.

As I happen to be part of a team that is creating an icon theme I want the theme to have consistency everywhere and that means covering those webapps icons too.

However I have no clue where the webapp icons names are or where they should go in the icon theme.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The .desktop files for the Unity webapps are located in ~/.local/share/applications

e.g. ~/.local/share/applications/GMailmailgooglecom.desktop, which contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GMail
Type=Application
Icon=GMail-mail.google.com
MimeType=
Actions=S0;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6;S7;S8;S9;S10;
Exec=unity-webapps-runner -n 'R01haWwA' -d 'mail.google.com' %u%
```

There you can find the name for the icon, which on my system is stored in ~/.icons

e.g.  ~/.icons/GMail-mail.google.com.png

I guess it could be anywhere in the standard icon lookup path as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following did the trick. I think for me the problems had something to do with a conflict with chrome. Could it be that you also installed chrome on your system? So I did the following:

1. Uninstall all chrome related packages
2. Uninstall all chromium webapp packages
3. Uninstall all webapp related packages (be carefull not to uninstall unity... thats what I did; but opening a terminal and reinstall it, solved it quickly)
4. Reboot
5. Install all webapp related packages
6. Install chromium webapp packages

After doing this, the symbols for the webapps appeared icon by icon when opening the respective pages.

Things which are still not working properly is Google Drive. Here seems to be the problem that the webapps have not recognized until today that Google Docs is called Google Drive since years now and has the URL https://drive.google.com Also for some reason the Gmail and Youtube webapp Icon is not appearing. But calendar, Google+ and Hangouts at least is working for me.